# Homebrew install specific version of truffle?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, truffle

would like to know how to install a specific version of truffle with homebrew, I need to install version 5.0.2, I tried different ways with npm but I am not able to install it

```
npm install -g truffle@5.0.2
```

I get as an error:

```
[1]
```

So thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to install something with homebrew, you need to use `brew` instead of `npm`, try this:

```sh
brew install truffle@5.0.2
```

Comment: I tried that, and it installs the last version of truffle, for me know: Truffle v5.4.8, not the v5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

There is a little trouble in your question (you say, that u need to install some package with brew, while trying to install it with NPM (node package manager(javascript tool(it is not related to homebrew in any way)))).

First you need to learn wether you want to install it with homebrew, or NPM, then you need to give a little more info about system (os version, npm version, etc), cuz its impossible to understand the error without context.
GL with that.